# Get variables from URL and convert to array

Tags: javascript

I need to retrieve variables from an URL.

I use this found function:

```
function getParams(str) {

    var match = str.replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']').match(/[^=&?]+\s*=\s*[^&#]*/g);
    var obj = {};

    for ( var i = match.length; i--; ) {
      var spl = match[i].split("=");
      var name = spl[0].replace("[]", "");
      var value = spl[1];

      obj[name] = obj[name] || [];
      obj[name].push(value);
    }

    return obj;
}

var urlexample = "http://www.test.it/payments/?idCliente=9&idPagamenti%5B%5D=27&idPagamenti%5B%5D=26"

var me = getParams(stringa);
```

The output is:

```
 {"idPagamenti":["26","27"],"idCliente":["9"]}
```

But `idCliente` is always NOT an array, so i'd like to retrieve:

```
{"idPagamenti":["26","27"],"idCliente": 9 }
```

This is the fiddle example

```js
function getParams(str) {
 
    var match = str.replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']').match(/[^=&?]+\s*=\s*[^&#]*/g);
 var obj = {};

 for ( var i = match.length; i--; ) {
   var spl = match[i].split("=");
   var name = spl[0].replace("[]", "");
   var value = spl[1];

   obj[name] = obj[name] || [];
   obj[name].push(value);
 }

    return obj;
}

var stringa = "http://www.test.it/payments/?idCliente=9&idPagamenti%5B%5D=27&idPagamenti%5B%5D=26"

var me = getParams(stringa);

$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("testing");
  console.log(me);
 $(".a").html(JSON.stringify(me));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">

</div>
```

Someone can help me to modify code?

Comment: You can use `[].concat(me[idCliente])` then you either concat the array or the number

Comment: `var foo = Array.isArray(bar) ? bar[0] : bar`

Comment: Why? Having a consistent dataset is much better.

Comment: if `idCliente` is always uniq, just use an `if else` statement in your `for` loop. so `if (name == 'idCliente') { obj[name] = value; }` else do what you already do :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your facing a real paradigm problem. Why idCliente wouldn't be an array but idPagamenti would be. You should have all array or none but not both. getParams() function can make this choice for you and you should probably change the way you are working with this.

Anyway, here is a getParams() function that replace any single-valued array to a value. Note that if you have only one idPagamenti in your URI, you will also have a single value for idPagamenti instead of an array.

```
function getParams(str) {

    var match = str.replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']').match(/[^=&?]+\s*=\s*[^&#]*/g);
    var obj = {};

    for ( var i = match.length; i--; ) {
      var spl = match[i].split("=");
      var name = spl[0].replace("[]", "");
      var value = spl[1];

      obj[name] = obj[name] || [];
      obj[name].push(value);
    }

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (obj[key].length === 1) {
            obj[key] = obj[key][0];
        }
    })
    return obj;
}

var urlexample = "http://www.test.it/payments/?idCliente=9&idPagamenti%5B%5D=27&idPagamenti%5B%5D=26"

var me = getParams(stringa);
```

If you know that you will always get ids as parameters, you can also add a parseInt() for each parameter by replacing `var value = spl[1];` with `var value = parseInt(spl[1], 10);`